# Consolidate nested, overlapping <strong> and <em> tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string of text that I am storing mark-up for separately. For example:

```
var content = {
    text: "a little white rabbit hops",
    style: [
        {
            type: "strong",
            start: 0,
            length: 8
         },
         {
            type: "em",
            start: 2,
            length: 14
         }
    ]
}
```

I am then parsing that into html, but the `em` tag has to be opened and closed twice to be properly formatted:

```
<strong>a <em>little</em></strong><em> white</em> rabbit hops
```

My question is: what is the best way to parse the html retrieved from the DOM to consolidate the separated `em` tags (or conceivably the `strong` tags: in my scenario either could be nested).

If I iterate over a `NodeList` of children (`p.getElementsByTagName('em')`) I would have to do multiple `for` loops and check the start/length of all nested tags. There has got to be an easier way, but I haven't thought of one - is there a library out there that handles this kind of formatting (or a way to to do this directly via the DOM)?

I am not using `jQuery` and don't want to add it to my project just for this. Any help is much appreciated!

---**EDIT**---

To clarify the question: this is essentially about translating the formatting into/out of the HTML, the issue is the best way to handle the tag nesting: i.e. even though there are two `em` child tags, there is really only one `em` formatted block (the end/start of `em` child tag 1 and 2 are contiguous)

Comment: Are the `styles` considered in isolation, or do you incrementally build the string, and each style's `start`, and `length` is affected by the previous one?

Comment: The styles are considered in isolation: i.e. the start/length are absolute values relative to the plain text, not to the html

Comment: @SjB If you wanna do it this way, `<strong>a <em>little</strong> white</em> rabbit hops`, you might get arrested!

Comment: Yeah, the overlapping tags are a no-no, and in fact, when using innterHTML to set the content of my <p> tag, both chrome and ff automatically format the html correctly. That being the case, when I read the html back from the DOM, I am left with my original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two functions for the conversion in either direction.

First the one that converts an HTML string to the content structure you described:

```
function htmlToContent(html) {
    // The object to fill and return:
    var content = {
        text: '',
        style: []
    };
    // Keep track of recently closed tags (i.e. without text following them as of yet)
    var closedStyles = [];

    // Recursive function
    function parseNode(elem) {
        var style;
        if (elem.nodeType === 3) {
            // This is a text node (no children)
            content.text += elem.nodeValue;
            // Any styles that were closed should be added to the content 
            // style array, as they cannot be "extended" any more
            [].push.apply(content.style, closedStyles);
            closedStyles = [];
        } else {
            // See if we can extend a style that was closed
            if (!closedStyles.some(function (closedStyle, idx) {
                if (closedStyle.type === elem.nodeName) {
                    style = closedStyle;
                    // Style will be extended, so it's no longer closed
                    closedStyles.splice(idx, 1);
                    return true; // exit ".some"
                }
            })) {
                // No style could be extended, so we create a new one
                style = {
                    type: elem.nodeName,
                    start: content.text.length,
                    length: 0
                };
            }
            // Recurse into the child nodes:
            [].forEach.call(elem.childNodes, function(child) {
                parseNode(child);
            });
            // set style length and store it as a closed one
            style.length = content.text.length - style.start;
            closedStyles.push(style);
        }
    }
    // Create a node with this html
    wrapper = document.createElement('p');
    wrapper.innerHTML = html;
    parseNode(wrapper);
    // Flush remaining styles to the result
    closedStyles.pop(); // Discard wrapper
    [].push.apply(content.style, closedStyles);
    return content;
}
```

This function first injects the HTML string into a DOM wrapper element, and then recurses into the node hierarchy to build the content structure. The main idea in this code is that it first collects closed nodes in a temporary `closedStyles` array. Only when it becomes certain that these cannot be used anymore for a merge with an upcoming node, they are added to the content structure. This happens when a text node is encoutered. If however tags close and open again without intermediate text, the matching style is located and extracted from this `closedStyles` array, and reused for extension.

The function that does the opposite could be defined as follows:

```
function contentToHtml(content) {
    var tags = [];
    // Build list of opening and closing tags with the offset of injection
    content.style.forEach(function (tag) {
        tags.push({
            html: '<' + tag.type + '>',
            offset: tag.start
        }, {
            html: '</' + tag.type + '>',
            offset: tag.start + tag.length
        });
    });
    // Sort this list by decreasing offset:
    tags.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.offset - a.offset;
    });
    var html = '';
    var text = content.text;
    // Insert opening and closing tags from end to start in text
    tags.forEach(function (tag) {
        // Prefix the html with the open/close tag and the escaped text that follows it
        html = tag.html + textToHtml(text.substr(tag.offset)) + html;
        // Reduce the text to the part that still needs to be processed
        text = text.substr(0, tag.offset);
    });
    // Remaining text:
    html = textToHtml(text) + html;
    // Create a node with this html, in order to get valid html tag sequences
    p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = html;
    // p.innerHTML will change here if html was not valid.
    return p.innerHTML;
}
```

This function first translates each of the styles to two objects, one representing the opening tag, and the other the closing tag. These tags are then inserted into the text at the right position (from then of the text to the beginning). Finally the trick you described yourself is applied: the resulting html is put in a dom object and taken out of it again. This way any invalid HTML tag sequence is fixed.

The function uses the `textToHtml` utility function, which could be defined as follows:

```
function textToHtml(text) {
    // See http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#use
    return text.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
}
```

You can see it work in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3deagxrd/), where an example HTML string is used that also includes nested tags of the same type. These are maintained.

Comment: thanks for the help! I didn't even think of walking each child node (javascript/DOM noob here): I was grabbing all the tags by tag name then doing some juggling to manage the open/closed state of each node. It all seemed very hackish and this way seems much cleaner. Cheers,

Comment: I see. Yes, doing that using the html string directly would be much more cumbersome... Good luck.